# How to change default dependencies implementations when starting new projects

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-3.1

When I create a new project the activity_main.xml file does not show the default "Hello World!" TextView. I found a video which corrected this by changing an "implementation" line in the build.gradle (Module:app) file. He changed the end of the second implementation line from beta01 to alpha1.

```
`dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}`
```

I suspect that some setting is off, either in the way I configure new projects to build, or some other possibility I'm completely unaware of. Is there a way to change what defaults under dependencies on a new project build? I'm not certain if this is the cause of the problem, or the symptom of a larger one. I cannot seem to follow the simplest of tutorials three steps in before getting errors which seem simple, but I cannot seem to resolve.

I'm new to Android and have some experience coding. I'm quite lost, however, because I can't seem to follow alongside simple tutorials. Any help would be great.

I'm using Android Studio 3.1.4

The video I reference (near 45s to 1m in): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpGqlBDqz_M&t=80s

I've also checked out the Gradle doc's to no avail: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild it

Comment: I've tried that, that's not the issue though. I'm wondering why every time I start a project it defaults to certain dependencies which cause my textviews, buttons, etc not appear in the design preview.